# Problema com download de arquivo em php

Tags: php, download

estou com o seguinte código para download de arquivo:

```
set_time_limit(0); // Define o tempo máximo de execução em 0 para as conexões lentas

    $arquivoLocal = "../arquivo/emboss/needle/Resultado/$resultado"; // caminho absoluto do arquivo

    // Verifica se o arquivo não existe
    if (!file_exists($arquivoLocal)) {
        echo "Arquivo não encontrado.";
        exit;
    }

    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$resultado.'"');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivoLocal));
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0');

    readfile($arquivoLocal);
```

O problema que estou é que ao clicar em enviar, o arquivo que está vindo para download é a pagina view que estou não o que coloquei no $arquivoLocal, juntamente a header onde está o filesize( $arquivoLocal) mostra o tamanho de download da view também, fiz um print_r(filesize($arquivoLocal) antes das header e nesse print recebo o tamanho certo do arquivo.
O problema que não estou entendendo é porque o readfile($arquivolocal) não está fazendo download do arquivo correto?

Comment: Elabore a pergunta um pouquinho melhor por favor.

Comment: Se o ficheiro for muito grande poderá causar problemas na função `readfile`. [Questão relacionada no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031301/php-readfile-not-working-for-me-and-i-dont-know-why)

Comment: Se passa pelo IF é porque o arquivo existe. Se não está vindo o arquivo correto pra baixar, talvez algum problema de permissão do servidor, aí ele está retornando para baixar a página em vez do arquivo. Fiz testes aqui, inclusive com arquivos de 10MB, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Seria problema de permissão no apache ? Estranho na header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($arquivoLocal)); ja dar o tamanho da view e não do arquivo que quero.

Comment: eu realizei um echo "<a href='../arquivo/emboss/needle/Resultado/hba_human.needle' download>download not open it</a>"; e o arquivo de download é o correto seria algo com o readfile ou os headers não pegar o arquivi correto?

Comment: Eu abri a view de download e com ela está vindo no final o arquivo de download dentro do arquivo da view